# Why Benetton Treviso and Zebre Parma plays Pro12 League?

Tags: rugby-union

Why do Benetton Treviso and Zebre Parma do not play in *Italian Eccellenza* (the most important national league) and play abroad in Pro12 League with teams from Great Britain and Ireland?

The winner of *Eccellenza* is the national champion team or not?

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that the top Welsh, Irish and Scottish teams play in the Pro12: because it's a higher standard of play, giving entry to things like the European Cup. As such, there isn't really a "national champion", just as there isn't in Wales, Ireland or Scotland.